# How to make homemade pinto beans taste like canned refried beans?

Tags: spices, beans

I see plenty of advice out there on how to make canned pinto beans taste delicious, but does anyone know how to recreate that *cheapo refrito* taste? I've tried countless combinations of freshly cooked pinto beans, salt, garlic, chili powder, onions...

They always seem to be missing some crucial element, and I don't mean the sitting-in-a-can-forever-flavor!

Comment: A little freshly ground and fried til just brown cumin seed can be helpful to getting the taste right.

Comment: Why would you want to do this to perfectly good pinto beans?  If you want canned, buy the canned!

Comment: @DougR. But bulk buying 25lbs of pinto beans from Costco is soo cheap!

Comment: I'll buy that for an answer.

Answer (score 17):

Lard is the fat of choice in many "el cheapo" canned refried beans, and could be what you are missing.

Comment: As soon as I saw the question on the sidebar, my brain said "lard!"

Answer (score 11):

My first guess would be: more salt than you think.  This is probably the main "secret" for most processed foods.

[Ortega Traditional Refried Beans](http://www.ortega.com/products/products_detail.php?id=13148) have 560 mg of sodium per serving (that's a serving of 131 g, making 3.5 servings in a standard can).  A 1/4 tsp of table salt has 590 mg.  If you're making the equivalent of 1 can of beans, you would have to put in a little over 3/4 tsp of salt.

If you're making a biggish pot,  starting with 1 kg of dry beans (makes about 2 kg cooked), that would be about 4 tsp (9.5 g) of salt.  Yeah, it's a lot.  You can think about whether you really want to do that.

Other suggestions I have heard: sugar and cinnamon.  Haven't tried it myself, though.

Comment: I'm amazed they're allowed to claim that a can contains a non-integer number of servings.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: AFAIK they don't have a choice.  In the US, food manufacturers used to be allowed to set their own serving sizes (until the mid-90s, I think), but there were obvious abuses where a manufacturer would set an absurdly small size so they could say "Only 50 calories per serving!"  Now they are set by the government; so every manufacturer of refried beans will give nutrition information based on a 131g serving, regardless of whether there's an integral number of servings in their particular can / box / package / etc.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: It looks like for foods that come in "discrete" units, the serving size can sometimes be rounded to the nearest unit.  E.g. if cookies have a standard serving size of 30g, and your cookies weigh 12g each, you can use a serving size of "3 cookies".  But this doesn't seem to apply to "continuous" products like canned beans.  I found some info at http://www.cnpp.usda.gov/sites/default/files/nutrition_insights_uploads/Insight22.pdf  Maybe this would make an interesting new question!

Comment: @NateEldredge you're right that there could be a new question in there. Note that "who comes up with servings" has already been asked though, so it would be about some more specific detail.

Answer (score 7):

You're missing fat in the equation.  The previous member suggests bacon but I don't know how you feel about the smoke flavor but fat will do you good.

Answer (score 6):

Try mashing the beans with butter and bacon drippings along with just a enough cumin so you can "tell" it's different but you can't taste the cumin.

Comment: Oh! That's exactly what I always do wrong; in addition to under-fatting I also *over-cumin!* Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You might be missing [epazote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dysphania_ambrosioides). IMHO an absolute must in any Mexican bean dishes. Do not overdo it though.

Comment: I do like epazote, including with beans, but I've never noticed its flavor in plain canned refried beans.

Answer (score 2):

Lard. It's all you need. There is usually a tub of it in the same part of the store as Crisco (vegetable shortening).

Comment: Maybe you want to explain how and when to use this lard? And why you think/know lard is all the OP needs?  And what is a crisco BTW?

Comment: @MarcLuxen: Crisco is a brand of vegetable shortening in the US.

Comment: crisco is NOT vegetable shortening. It is cotton seed oil. It is NOT a food, whether it's sold as a food or not.